# Different results for contract call from different nodes

Tags: web3js, contract-development, blockchain

When I try to call my contract and do some calculation on smart contract my QuickNode node shows different (and very off) results than public nodes. Does smart contract calls result depend on the node? While nodes don't get paid to do this calculations, Is there a guarantee to get correct result?

My QuickNode call returns '235465205454505465' while DefiBit node returns 0 which is the correct answer.

Comment: lol! only you will know what is happening with your stuff

Comment: Can you share the contract you are calling and on what network?

Comment: Sorry it's a private contract for my client. My question is, Can nodes refuse to do calculations or do them wrong?

Comment: Do them wrong ? Yes in a way, if they are not in sync with other nodes. Basically a node returns its "truth" or its state.
Refuse to do calculations? Depends on what protocols the node is running.

Comment: If the nodes are synchronized at the same block they should perform the same computation with the same state and return the same value. It is always possible a bug in the software.